# Display past 4 survey results from JQuery.survey

Tags: jquery, survey

I am making something for work.  It is a highly repetitive task and it will be useful to fill out a small survey about the task that can be referred back to in the short term (like 5 minutes)

I love the [jquery.survey module.](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Survey) 
The survey looks great.  Now I could use a hint or some help on getting the output from that survey to save for 3-4 sessions to be display in a sidebar.

I have tech limitations and can only use javascript.  I can't write to a txt log and read from that (ie 6 issues) and I can't use PHP or server software because I do not have access to it.  I am limited to just a html file on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add to the DOM by overriding the "Submit" form button and pushing the resulting form data into a `<div>` or `<p>` that you display on the same page.

This is, however, highly fragile as any reload will wipe out the data (since you can't save to disk via javascript limitations)... what you're saving to is the browser in-memory state of your page.

If you actually want to save the work you had entered, you need local filesystem access or server access, there's just no way around it due to the sandboxing of browser javascript.